# .tmux.conf: How can I conditionally set a color variable?

Tags: unix, terminal, colors, environment-variables, tmux

Sometimes I use a light-colored terminal, sometimes a dark one. I export a `THEME` environment variable to conditionally set colors in my `.bash_profile` and `.vimrc`. I'm trying to do the same in my `.tmux.conf`, but it's proving difficult.
[image: light terminal][image: dark terminal]
This works,

```
if '[[ "$THEME" =~ dark ]]' 'set -g status-bg colour233' \
                            'set -g status-bg "#ffffff"'
```

but gets cumbersome. Case in point:

```
if '[[ "$THEME" =~ dark ]]' "set  -g status-right \" #S #[fg=#9BD4FF]::#[fg=default] #h #[fg=#9BD4FF]::#[fg=default] #(sysctl vm.loadavg | cut -d ' ' -f 3-5) \"" \
                            "set  -g status-right \" #S #[fg=#000000]::#[fg=default] #h #[fg=#000000]::#[fg=default] #(sysctl vm.loadavg | cut -d ' ' -f 3-5) \""
```

I tried conditionally setting color variables inside `.tmux.conf` but can't get them to work.

```
if '[[ "$THEME" =~ dark ]]' 'BG_COLOUR=colour233' 'BG_COLOUR=#ffffff'
set -g status-bg $BG_COLOUR
```

This gives me a 'bad colour' error when I start tmux. I tried quoting (`'BG_COLOUR="colour233"'`), I tried setenv (`'setenv -g BG_COLOUR colour233'`), and I tried setenv with quoting (`'setenv -g BG_COLOUR "colour233"'`), but nothing works yet. Is there a way to do this cleanly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following steps should help:

1. Break out your status line configuration into two different files: 
         one configured with the colors you want for the dark theme,
         and another with the colors you want for the light theme.
2. Save those files in your home directory (I made a .tmux directory and they live there)
3. Add something like the following to your .tmux.conf:

   `if '[[ "$THEME" =~ dark ]]' 'source ~/.tmux/dark_status.conf'`

You may also want to add a conditional for your light theme.